# Jquery 'Justified Gallery' reload/reinitilse

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

Im using the jquery 'Justified Gallery' plugin to display some pictures. Im also uploading pictures to the picture folder. Im trying to reinitilise or reload the gallery when the image is uploaded (this example I just use a refresh button).

The documentation states:"can be called again to update the layout (after add or remove of images)". But when I attempt this it is ignored and requires the page to be reloaded to make the change.

This should be simple...what am I doing wrong?

```
//initilise gallery
$(window).load(function() 
{
   $('#layout-gallery').justifiedGallery({
      rowHeight : 300,
      margins : 15,
      captions :  true,
      imagesAnimationDuration : 1000
    });

    //refresh gallery
    $('#refresh').on('mousedown', function(e) 
    {
          $('#layout-gallery').justifiedGallery({
                rowHeight : 300,
                margins : 15,
                captions :  true,
                imagesAnimationDuration : 1000
           });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me being stupid...it was reloading the gallery! I needed to re-call the php function that gathered the images, so did this:

```
function initiliseGallery()
{    
    $.get('php/data/output-layouts.php?outputGallery=true',function(data)
    {
        $('.gallery-container').html(data);

        $('#layout-gallery').justifiedGallery(
        {
            rowHeight : 300,
            margins : 15,
            captions :  true,
            imagesAnimationDuration : 1000
        });
    });
 }
```

Which loads (via ajax) php images wrapped in 'layout-gallery' div into the 'gallery-container' div(on main page). Then re-initiled the plugin. Calling the method when uploading is complete reloaded gallery contents.